# Cannot connect to MySQL Server and have no idea why

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, ado.net

I am trying to connect to MySQL server

Screenshot from MySQL Workbench:

[image: Screenshot from MySQL Workbench]

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace C_sharp_test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                string connectionString = "server=localhost;uid=root;pwd=***********;database=terra_incognita_online";
                SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection();
                sqlConnection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
                sqlConnection.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("open");
                sqlConnection.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("close");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
```

I have no idea what to do, please help

Answer (score 3):

Replace "SqlConnection" with "MySqlConnection" and that will work.

```
 namespace C_sharp_test
 {
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           try
           {
               string connectionString = "server=localhost;uid=root;pwd=***********;database=terra_incognita_online";
               MySqlConnection sqlConnection = new MySqlConnection();
               sqlConnection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
               sqlConnection.Open();
               Console.WriteLine("open");
               sqlConnection.Close();
               Console.WriteLine("close");
           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(e);
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Also, Install nuget package MySql.Data;

And Add Reference

```
 using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to connect to a MySQL database server with classes intended for SQL Server. They use different protocols, so that doesn't work (and almost certainly never will).

Have a look at the [MySQL connector for .NET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/), if you want to use MySQL rather than SQL Server.